# How to avoid delayed evaluation in Condition used in a function definition

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I would like to define a function (below, f) that evaluates only under the condition that some expression is True. The condition is to be specified now, and I don't want it to change for the purposes of the function evaluation even when the variables on which the condition depends (below, z) might change. Here is my attempt at a (very simplified) version to illustrate the problem:

```
In[1]:= z=666                                                                     

Out[1]= 666

In[2]:= f[n1_,n2_] /; UnsameQ[0, n1 + z * n2]  := n1^2 + n2^2
```

which then gives:

```
In[3]:= ?f                                                                      
Global`f

f[n1_, n2_] /; 0 =!= n1 + z*n2 := n1^2 + n2^2
```

That makes sense, but is not what I want; I would like the result of the definition to be

```
f[n1_,n2_] /; UnsameQ[0, n1 + 666 * n2] := n1^2 + n2^2;
```

even if I subsequently change the value of z. I could of course just define the second version by hand, but this is to be done for many complicated functions with complicated sets of arguments, and parameters (playing the role of z) that change often and could depend on interactive user input.

Is there some simple modification to achieve this? In other words, if at some stage of my program z has taken on the value 666, what should I do instead to get the number 666 hardwired into the condition in my function definition? Not being an expert, I thought maybe

```
ff[n1_, n2_] /; UnsameQ[0, Evaluate[n1 + z * n2]] := n1^2 + n2^2
```

might do it, but that doesn't give what I want either.

Comment: `z = 666; 

Clear[f]; 

f[n1_, n2_] = ConditionalExpression[n1^2 + n2^2, n1 + z*n2 != 0]`

Comment: `With[{z=z}, f[n1_,n2_] /; UnsameQ[0, n1 + z * n2]  := n1^2 + n2^2]`. The function `With` replaces _literally_, with the values that exist the moment it is invoked.

Comment: Thanks, Bob. Your solution works if I define f with `=`. However, it seems that if I want delayed assignment of f, with `:=`, then z remains unset? (I admit it isn't clear from my simplified version why I would want delayed assignment.)

Comment: Thanks, Marius. That works for me. In fact, `With[]` seems to be the secret weapon that will help me with several other things as well...

Comment: @user72533 - If you want to use `:=` then use `f[n1_, n2_] := 
 Evaluate@ConditionalExpression[n1^2 + n2^2, n1 + z*n2 != 0]` Note that if you want to insure that your comment is seen by a specific person you need to use `@username`